Examples of proper irreducible subalgebra in $M_2 (\mathbb{R})$ and $M_4 (\mathbb{R})$
We known from Burnside theorem the following fact: For an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{F}$, the only irreducible subalgebra in $M_n (\mathbb{F}), (n \ge 2)$ is the algebra itself $M_n (\mathbb{F})$. I want to construct examples of proper irreducible algebras in $M_2 (\mathbb{R})$ and $M_4 (\mathbb{R})$ over an algebraically non-closed field $\mathbb{R}$.
Consider matrices $A = E_{21} - E_{12}$, $E = E_{11} + E_{22}$ and the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ generated by them $\mathcal{A} = \langle A, E \rangle$, where $E_{ij}$ - a matrix unit.
We have $A^2 = -E$. Suppose that exists such proper $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, that $\mathcal{A} U \subseteq U$. Then in some basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ the matrix $A$ should have diagonal view. But $\mathrm{det} (A - t E) = t^2 + 1$ doesn't have real roots in $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $A$ is not diagonalizable. Сontradiction. Then $U = \mathbb{R}^2$.
Is this example correct and is this the correct explanation of the irreducibility of algebra $\mathcal{A}$?
I think for $M_4 (\mathbb{R})$ we can put algebra $\mathcal{B} = \mathrm{diag} (\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{A})$.
